# Присваивание значения группе groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть дата фрейм вида:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [111, 222, 333, 333, 444, 555, 555], 'Номер': ['1', '2','3', '4', '5', '6', '7']})
```

Требуется присвоить случайный номер между 1 и 3 всем ID, но с условием - если ID одинаковый, им присваивается одинаковый номер.

Основная цель - сгруппировать все ID под определенный набор групп, причем, одинаковые ID должны быть под одним номером, а количество групп генерируется случайным образом в диапазоне между заданными числами. Разные группы могут быть под одним номером.

Пробовал через группировку - не сработало:

```py
for group in df['Номер'].groupby(df['ID']):
        df['Номер'] = np.random.randint(1, 4, size=len(df))
```

Каким образом поместить одинаковые ID под один номер, который генерируется случайным образом?

Comment: Нужно из `group` добыть `ID` и дальше `df.loc[df['ID'] == id_, 'Номер'] = np.random...` Но в идеале лучше сделать без цикла. Для этого сделать словарь из уникальных `ID` и такого же числа рандомов, а потом `df['Номер'] = df['ID'].map(словарь)`

Comment: ну вот в вашем примере 5 разных групп. как можно присвоить 5-ти группам три id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если работать с объектом группировки в groupby через отдельную функцию с group, работает:

```
    def assign_random_number(group):
        group['Номер'] = np.random.randint(1, 4)
        return group

    df['Номер'] = df.groupby('ID',group_keys=False).apply(assign_random_number)['Номер']
```

Получаем требуемый результат:

```
 ID   Номер
111      1
222      3
333      2
333      2
444      3
444      3
555      1
555      1
```

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: Отредактировал, ответ рабочий.

Comment: я обновил свой ответ. для подобных задач целесообразно использовать метод `.tranform`.

Answer (score 2):

Самое простое решение - просвоить `id` на основании номера группы метода `groupby`:

```
df["group_id"] = df.groupby("ID").ngroup()
```

df:

```
    ID Номер  group_id
0  111     1         0
1  222     2         1
2  333     3         2
3  333     4         2
4  444     5         3
5  555     6         4
6  555     7         4
```

Другое дело, как вы 5ти группам будете присваивать три уникальных id - это вопрос тот еще...

**UPDATE**

Если id могут повторяться, то сделать можно так:

```
df["group_id"] = df.groupby("ID").transform(lambda x: np.random.randint(1, 4, len(x)))
```

df:

```
    ID Номер  group_id
0  111     1         3
1  222     2         1
2  333     3         1
3  333     4         1
4  444     5         1
5  555     6         2
6  555     7         2
```

Comment: Разные группы могут быть под одним номером, а количество групп генерируется случайным образом в диапазоне между заданными числами.

Comment: С transform выдает ошибку-ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column group_id

Comment: @Ilay значит ваши реальные исходные данные отличаются от предоставленных в вопросе.